# JavaFx AreaChart drawn with parts filled wrong

Tags: java, css, javafx, charts

When trying to create an area chart I've encoutered the following issue: the plot is drawn with a part of its area filled when(to my knowledge) it shouldn't be.
The plot looks like this:

[image]

and I want the plot to look like this:

[image]

I attempted to find a javafx or css property that controls this behavior but I haven't found one. Any tutorials regarding charts I've found do not seem to do anything to force the behavior I want - it seems to normally be the default one.

I've also tried to:

- remove the CSS class
- change the axis types to `<Number,Number>`
- change the parent of the plot to a `StackPane`
- update the JDK (to jdk1.8.0_131)

and it hasn't helped.

I've tried printing the data to console to verify that it is not malformed:

```
02:00->17
05:00->13
08:00->14
11:00->15
14:00->17
17:00->17
20:00->16
23:00->12
```

but the data seems fine.

Here is the code creating the plot:

```
package bug_reproduce;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private static final String FXML_MAIN_TEMPLATE = "/fxml/MainPage.fxml";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent pane = loader.load(App.class.getResource(FXML_MAIN_TEMPLATE).openStream());

        StackPane hourly = (StackPane) pane.lookup("#hourly");

        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<Weather> list = new ArrayList<Weather>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 24; i+=3) {
            list.add(new Weather(i+":00", rnd.nextInt(15)+10));
        }

        hourly.getChildren().clear();
        createPlot(list, hourly);

        Scene myScene = new Scene(pane, 1280, 720);
        primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Weather");
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(720);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(1280);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void createPlot(List<Weather> list, StackPane parent) {
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Hour");
        yAxis.setLabel("Temperature");

        AreaChart<String,Number> chart = new AreaChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        yAxis.forceZeroInRangeProperty().set(true);

        chart.setTitle("Hourly weather forecast");
        chart.getStyleClass().add("hourlyChart");
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);

        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();    
        for(Weather w : list) {
            String time = w.time;
            Number value = w.temperature;
            XYChart.Data datum = new XYChart.Data(time, value);
            series.getData().add(datum);
        }

        chart.getData().add(series);
        parent.getChildren().add(chart);
    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The `Weather` class:

```
package bug_reproduce;

public class Weather {

    String time;
    Number temperature;

    public Weather(String t, Number tem) {
        time = t;
        temperature = tem;
    }
}
```

The stylesheet:

```
* {
    -fx-fill:WHITE;
    -fx-font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#hourly {
    -fx-background-color:#736591;
}

.hourlyChart .chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.hourlyChart .chart-vertical-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
}

.hourlyChart .chart-horizontal-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: #fafafa;
}

.hourlyChart .chart-alternative-row-fill {
    -fx-fill: transparent;
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
    -fx-stroke-width: 0;
}

.hourlyChart .default-color0.chart-series-area-line { -fx-stroke: #00ccee; }
.hourlyChart .default-color0.chart-series-area-fill { -fx-fill: rgba(250,250,250,0.6) }
```

The fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane id="hourly" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" stylesheets="@/css/weather.css">

</StackPane>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. The CSS doesn't give me anything resembling the color scheme you posted in the images, either. Can you expand this to a [MCVE]?

Comment: @James_D Done, I tried to cut out as much unrelated code as possible. The code [still produces the bug for me.](http://i.imgur.com/9JhHrjt.png)

Comment: Yeah, I see it now. Seems like it is painting the fill twice over portions of the graph, so the opacity of the `rgb(250, 250, 250)` is different over the portion that is covered twice (i.e. it should all be the lighter, near-white, color, not the darker grey)?

Comment: @James_D I wanted it to look like it does in the second image I provided (I've just used software to edit the bugged image). Why is it even painting the fill above the designated area though? That is what I can't wrap my head around the most...

Comment: I had an idea. I added these two lines: `list.add(new Weather("0:00", 0));`, `list.add(new Weather("24:00", 0));` before and after the loop creating the data respectively to "snap" the plot to the X axis. It now draws [something like this](http://i.imgur.com/mfz2q63.png). Now the fill doesn't fill the area above the line(so works like I want it to) but it completely ignores the fill opacity.... what...?

Comment: Yeah, I fully get the issue. Looks like it is doing an extra fill between the last point and the first, no? So the portion that is double-filled is too dark (because its opacity is 0.6*0.6=0.36) and there are some portions that get filled that shouldn't. Chart API is pretty badly written in general (nodes that are properties of the data class, wtf?) and is buggy. I think I would try using a numeric x-axis if possible, and formatting the tick interval and tick labels on the x-axis.

Comment: Are you sure your fix is really ignoring the opacity? Set it really low in the CSS and see if it changes...

Comment: @James_D Omg. I did what you suggested and set the opacity to 0.05, it didn't change anything, so I changed the color. It didn't change anything... I asked myself: where is the color coming from, then? ... the `*` selector. Once I removed the `-fx-fill ` from the `* `it seems to work flawlessly. With or without the "snapping" to x-axis. I don't fully understand why, but it is okay now.